# MySQL Derived Table Subquery

Tags: mysql

I have developed the following join with a sub-query in MySQL 5.5;
it all works as it should, however I am unable to make work the last commented line.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT cat_name, fam_surname, pet_max_cost
FROM (SELECT cat_name, fam_surname, SUM(pet_cost) AS 'pet_max_cost'
FROM pet_unit_cost
LEFT JOIN pet_full_names
USING (petID)
GROUP BY cat_name) AS myquery;
-- WHERE myquery.pet_max_cost = (SELECT MAX(myquery.pet_max_cost) FROM myquery);
```

Comment: Even ignoring the last line, I'm afraid none of the rest of the query makes much sense. It may not throw an error, but it certainly won't return a meaningful result. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query and start over.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, I solved the issue myself (and yes it did not make much sense). However I do not understand the why of -1 to somebody that is clearly not an expert and it's trying her best to learn a database system on her own after work. I thought this site was friendlier. No worries, all good anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the result from 3 tables but you set the alias for one

```
cat_name,
fam_surname,
SUM(pet_cost) AS 'pet_max_cost'
```

You have to select one table for one alias

Comment: `AS pet_max_cost` is the alias for the aggregate column, nothing to do with the table aliases. The tables are only two as per the Select statement in the subquery.